# Extraction of the data arrays using bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I have big logs consisted of the several data arrays separated by the keywords e.g

```
Data1:
string 1
string 2
...
string n


Data2:
string 1
string 2
...
string n

Data3:
string 1
string 2
...
string n
```

using combination of the bash utilities I need to extract only first array consisted of data1 and all of its strings prior to the data2 keyword (but not the data2 and data2) in the separate log file.

```
Data1:
string 1
string 2
...
string n
```

I'll be thankful for any suggestions!

Thanks!

James

Comment: Show what you've tried and what is your expected output.

Comment: Files don't contain arrays; they contains a stream of bytes. You need to be more specific about how your files are formatted.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `sed`:

```
sed '/^Data2:/,$ d' < big.log
```

That says process the standard input line by line, deleting those lines between the first one matching the regular expression `/^Data2:/` and the last line of the input, inclusive, all using the contents of file `big.log` as the standard input.

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
sed -n '/^Data2:/ q; p' < big.log
```

That instructs `sed` to quit when it first sees a line matching the regular expression `/^Data2:/`.  The ordinary default action of printing the (possibly edited) input line is suppressed to avoid printing the `Data2:` line, but other lines up to that one are explicitly printed.

You could apply `sed` in similar ways to filter out the data for keywords other than the first.  For example, if you had keywords `DataFirst`, `Data321`, `DataPQR`, and `DataLast`, in that order, then you could filter out the data for `Data321` and `DataPQR` like so:

```
sed -n '/^DataLast:/ q; /^Data321:/,/^DataLast:/ p' < big.log
```

The main trick here is that `sed` processes only one line at a time, so except for the last block in the file, you don't know you've reached the end of a block until you see the first line of the next one.  There are other ways around that than the one I've presented, but none of them are quite so simple.

Comment: is it possible to do it in more flexible way to indicate name of the first and last keywords within the command >> e,g to chose segments in the middle of the initial big.log e.g data3 is between data2 and data 4

Comment: @user3470313, yes, as I said.  I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: also how it's possible to pipe sed output to the AWK input. e.g I've tried to make further filtration of the data produced by SED using AWK : sed '/^Receptor:/,$ d' < ${file} | awk -v n=${res}'BEGIN { OFS = FS = "," } $2 == n { print $NF }' > ${output}/${f_n}.log           However  the operation has not been finished.

Comment: There is nothing special about `sed` that changes how you would pipe its output to another program.  However, do note that the first `sed` command reads the whole input file, which is not efficient if the overall file is much longer than the part you want to extract.  The second alternative should be more efficient.  Try running each without piping the output to see how long it takes to finish.